# Possible to view history of apps LOOKED at on Google Play?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, history

I was wondering, is it possible to view a history of apps I looked at on Google Play, but didn't necessarily download?

I went down a lengthy rabbit hole of suggested apps and then my Play Store app suddenly crashed...

I am hoping against all hope there might be a general viewing history. I am already aware of how to see a list of currently installed apps, and a list of apps I have (ever) downloaded.

If no such list/history exists or can be cleverly made, perhaps I shall lookup apps through the browser in the future, since surely I would be able to see a history as it would appear like any other webpage visited I would think. However this would certainly be less convenient and would lack the other features and benefits that are a part of the actual app.

Anyways, thanks for your insight and your time.
Barrage

Comment: Doesn't seem so. I can only find the "recent searches" and the list of recent actions (such as posted reviews).

Comment: https://myactivity.google.com

Answer (score 0):

There is no option and actually from my experience, spending countless hours on finding a solution for such a minor problem is not good. It only brings headaches.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/239456)

Comment: How did you decide that this is a critique or a request for clarification if I may ask?

Comment: That's the standard verbiage provided by StackExchange.  I didn't write it. :)

Comment: I understand. Its not a critique, its not for clarification also. Actually the point was that certainly there is no option and actually from my experience, spending countless hours on finding a solution for such a minor problem is not good. It only brings headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the Play Store app, nor the Google Takeout offers this data.

It is in the interests of Google to keep a track of visited/seen apps by a user so as to customize its recommendations to that user, but the data collected is not available to the user. You might want to create a support request in the [Google Play Community](https://support.google.com/googleplay/community?hl=en) to get this data, but my guess is that you are likely to see no useful response there. Good luck.

Furthermore, and this is just a wild recommendation, if you are a EU citizen you *might* be able to get a hold of this data if you formally request it. See [What personal data and information can an individual access on request?](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rules-business-and-organisations/dealing-citizens/what-personal-data-and-information-can-individual-access-request_en).